# Sample Data M2 dev 1.0beta install via cmd raise Undefined method

Tags: magento2-dev-beta, sample-data

[image]

I'm using windows 8.1 with xampp 1.83 PHP5.5.15
i have cloned and installed magento by browser but when install sampledata step by cmd. It got error like below. I have config everything, setup depends packages like devdocs guide
what i'm missing?
Many thanks all you guys

Answer (score 0):

Download/Clone your magento2 code from [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/master)

Sample data working for master branch only. So don't try sample data with develop branch.